# iOS FBDialogs with one FBOpenGraphAction Uploading multiple photos

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to share multiple photos as open graph objects with one single action. Each photo object have a image url.
I can achieve share one photo object with one action per time, but I couldn't figure out how to share multiple photo objects at once. Any ideas?

the code I'm using is as follows:

```
id<FBGraphObject> photo =
[FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"photo"
                                        title:@"photo title"
                                        image:photoURL
                                          url:photoURL
                                  description:@""];

id<FBOpenGraphAction> shareAction = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
[shareAction setObject:photo forKey:@"photo"];

[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:shareAction
                                      actionType:@"share"
                             previewPropertyName:@"photo"
                                         handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                             if(error) {
                                                 NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                             } else {
                                                 NSLog(@"Success!");
                                             }
                                         }];
```